# Convert varchar to float without losing data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mariadb

I have a list of latitude and longitudinal values in my table of type `varchar`. I want them to be `float`. How do I convert `varchar` to `float`?

For example:
`36.26056695` of type `varchar` should be converted `36.26056695` of type `float`.

`-99.11080846` of type `varchar` should be converted `-99.11080846` of type `float`

Comment: See this for MySQL : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: Please clarify: Are you trying to `alter` the column definitions to a `float` or manipulating them in a `select` statement without loss of precision?

Comment: Which is it?  mysql/mariadb?  Or sql-server?

Comment: MySQL's `FLOAT` is good to about 1.7 meters or 5.6 feet.  Is that OK?

Answer (score 2):

Use **Cast** operator

For Example

**SELECT**  **CAST**( '36.26056695' **AS** **float**) FROM **TABLE**

Comment: I have a list 10,000 values. I want to change the entire column using a single command

Comment: ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col FLOAT NOT NULL;

Comment: TO use this cast function  it increase query time, any other solution

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by "losing data".

If you mean without loss of precision, "float" will be unreliable; it can only reliably store multiples of a power of two (.125, .25, .375, etc....)

If you just mean convert the fields without them going blank, the best bet is something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `the_table` 
   ADD COLUMN `dec_val` NOT NULL DECIMAL(11, 8)
;

UPDATE `the_table` 
   SET `dec_val` = CAST(`str_val` AS DECIMAL(11, 8))
;

ALTER TABLE `the_table` 
   DROP COLUMN `str_val`
;

-- The below is only needed if you wanted to do something like rename the 
-- new column to the same name as the original. Otherwise, you could just
-- have created the new column with the desired name.
ALTER TABLE `the_table` 
   CHANGE COLUMN `dec_val` `desired_column_name` NOT NULL DECIMAL(11, 8)
;
```

You could use FLOAT instead of DECIMAL of course, but this way preserves the exact values.

Note: Just changing the original column's definition to DECIMAL(11, 8) ***might*** work, but this allows you to inspect the converted values (after the UPDATE) before you drop the original ones.

Comment: 8 decimal places is overkill -- it's precise enough to distinguish one flake of dandruff from another.  6 places is precise enough to distinguish two people embraced in a kiss (16cm / 6 inches).

Comment: @RickJames I was just going with the data the question provided.

Comment: OK, then my comments are directed at the OP, not you.